# Font size and family for a tile's title

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-tile

Simple question but I havent found the answer. What is the font name and size that is used for the tile's title (like the title "Internet Explorer" on that tile)?

Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `FontFamily` is `PhoneFontFamilySemiBold` and `FontSize` is `PhoneFontSizeNormal`.

The code snippet below is from the [toolkit's](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) `HubTile` control where you can pretty much find all the information about the style of the tile. :)

```
<TextBlock x:Name="BackTitleBlock" Grid.Row="1" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                    Margin="10,0,0,6"
                                    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
```

Comment: Just an update, the latest version of the silverlight toolkit can be found [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/).