# What is the correct font style for Windows Phone 8 live tile content?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I am creating custom secondary flip tile for a Windows phone 8 app by generating front and back images as backgrounds.
In order to maintain control over the length and font size displayed text labels i am rendering them as part of the background image, and basically have all the text resources of the tile empty.

I am looking for the default stiles of both titles and back content such as font size, font family, font weight, character spacing etc.

Can someone point me to the right documentation. I was not able to find anything.
My best approach to date was to use screenshot of a system default tile and use it as a background of my custom template and to tweak the properties of the text blocks in order to mimic the same look and feel, but i dislike this approach as it produces unreliable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of all pre-defined themes in Windows Phones 
[Theme resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the exact style myself, but here is a similar question, where you can find relevant answer
[Font size and family for a tile's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429950/font-size-and-family-for-a-tiles-title)

If you are interested in the toolkit, here is link to the latest version [The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)